# QGIS: Merging neighbouring polygon leads to multipart polygon

Tags: qgis, merge

I have to merge a lot of neighbouring polygons and for some of them I always end up with a multipart polygon even though the two polygons share multiple vertices and edges without space in between. Sometimes all shared edges are still contained, sometimes only a couple.
What could be the cause of that?

[image]

Comment: Probably small slivers. Use topology/geometry checker plugin. Can you provide sample data?

Comment: I'd assume your shared edges do not have coincidental topology and run v.clean tool with a suitable tolerance (you might try several) and see if you can merge the polygons in the cleaned layer in the way you expect.  The produced layers are temporary so you would need to export to a permanent layer if you get something you like.  The v.clean tool takes a bit of learning to use and its documentation isn't great, but it is well worth learning as a way to fix many topological errors in one run.

Comment: Could you please share those 2 polygons, I am interested to look at this issue as well.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, here are two of these polygons (not exactly the two from the screenshot, but the issue is always the same) 
https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/55ec5a5b-bc44-4b64-8cb3-c0c9edd60bce

I'd assume something like not matching topology as well but the way these polygons are generated is by splitting them from a larger polygon. With split I'd assume that the newly generated vertices are equal at the border for both polygons.
I've run check validity and it outputs the merged polygon as valid geometry. (Which I guess it is, since it's a multipart polygon)

Comment: @John I tried v.clean with some different tolerances, but no changes so far. Still the same problem with the polygons of the output.